# Duplicate tag windows-service and windows-services

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The tag [windows-service](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-service) has 195 questions, [windows-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-services) got 25.

Comment: Needs moar merge!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a perfectly cromulent merge. Will investigate and update.

It was entirely appropriate. Merge applied, thesaurus updated.

Comment: +1 for cromulent usage of the word `cromulent`.