# Duplicate tag [service] and [services]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I wanted to report a tag that seems a duplicate;

[service](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/service) with 276 questions tagged, and

[services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/services) with 433 question tagged.

I think that is similar to this meta question [Q: Duplicate tag windows-service and windows-services](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3748/duplicate-tag-windows-service-and-windows-services)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quick look at the questions using those tags and I agree that there is not real distinction between [service](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/service) and [services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/services).

I have merged the tags and created the tag synonym mapping services → service.
(Convention is to remove the plural and point it to the singular version of the noun.)

The resulting stats:

- [services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/services) has been removed from 432 questions
- and to 426 questions the replacement [service](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/service) has been added instead.